# Sum rows with same values and write it in new cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I have the following table:

| OrderNumber | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 |
| 123 | 3 |
| 333 | 5 |
| 333 | 6 |
| 555 | 8 |
| 555 | 9 |

My goal is to sum all OrderNumbers with the same values (e.g. for OrderNumber 123 the sum should be 5) and output the result in a new row.

The output should be like this:

| OrderNumber | Value | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2 | 5 |
| 123 | 3 | 5 |
| 333 | 5 | 11 |
| 333 | 6 | 11 |
| 555 | 8 | 17 |
| 555 | 9 | 17 |

I've seen some formulas beginning with =SUM(A2:A6;A2;B2:B6). Important to me is that the searching criteria must be dynamically because my table has about 1k rows.

Do you have any references or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `SUMIF()` function.

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$7,A2,$B$2:$B$7)
```

If you are a ***Microsoft 365*** user then can try `BYROW()` for one go.

```
=BYROW(A2:A7,LAMBDA(x,SUMIF(A2:A7,x,B2:B7)))
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to show unique order number then sum values then can try `=LET(x,UNIQUE(A2:A7),y,SUMIFS(B2:B7,A2:A7,x),CHOOSE({1,2},x,y))`

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact reason why the "Subtotals" feature has been invented:

[image]